# All pages inside index.php good or bad?

Tags: jquery, navigation

I just wanna ask if this is good or not https://jsfiddle.net/grzyp7wL/

Is it good to make navigation menu like that, to have them all in the same page or to split like index.php contact.php about.php etc

Thanks in advance :)

You can also see the code here:

function toolbar_section()

```
global $variables;
$variables['menu_buttons'] = array(
    'home' => array(
        'title' => 'Home',
        'href' => 'index.php',
        'show' => true,
    ),
    'news' => array(
        'title' => 'News',
        'href' => 'index.php?action=news',
        'show' => true,
    ),
    'about' => array(
        'title' => 'About us',
        'href' => 'index.php?action=about',
        'show' => true,
    ),
);

    $menu_buttons = array();
foreach($variables['menu_buttons'] as $act => $button)
{
    if(!empty($button['show']))
    {
        $button['active'] = true;
        $menu_buttons[$act] = $button;
    }
}
$variables['menu_buttons'] = $menu_buttons;

echo '
    <nav>
    <ul>';

    foreach($variables['menu_buttons'] as $act => $button)
    {
        $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $class = (GetCurrentPageAdress() == $button['href']) ? 'active' : '';
        echo '<a href="'.$button['href'].'"><li class="'.$class.'" id="button_'.$act.'">'.$button['title'].'</li></a>';
    }

echo '
    </ul>
    </nav>';
```

function content_section()

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{
    if($_GET['action'] == 'news')
    {
    //news page
}
else if($_GET['action'] == 'about')
    {
    //about page
}
```